# Converting if clauses to optionals

Tags: swift

I'm attempting to convert a lot of if clauses to optionals in Swift. I'm still getting an error for the `let name` statement. The error I'm getting is:

```
Type 'int' does not conform to protocol 'StringLiteralConvertible'.
```

I have two questions:

1. Will my new code have the same use as my old code?
2. How can I get rid of this error?

Thanks.

> Old Code:

```
class func jsonAsUSDAIdAndNameSearchResults (json: NSDictionary) -> [(name: String, idValue: String)] {

    var usdaItemsSearchResults: [(name: String, idValue: String)] = []
    var searchResult: (name: String, idValue: String)

    if json["hits"] != nil {
        let results: [AnyObject] = json["hits"] as [AnyObject]
        for itemDictionary in results {
            if itemDictionary["_id"] != nil {
                let idValue:String = itemDictionary["_id"] as String
                if itemDictionary["fields"] != nil {
                    let fieldsDictionary: NSDictionary = itemDictionary["fields"] as NSDictionary
                    if fieldsDictionary["item_name"] != nil {
                        let name: String = fieldsDictionary["item_name"] as String
                        searchResult = (name: name, idValue: idValue)
                        usdaItemsSearchResults += [searchResult]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return usdaItemsSearchResults
}
```

> New code:

```
class func jsonAsUSDAIdAndNameSearchResults (json: NSDictionary) -> [(name: String, idValue: String)] {

    var usdaItemsSearchResults: [(name: String, idValue: String)] = []
    var searchResult: (name: String, idValue: String)

    if json["hits"] != nil {
        let results: [AnyObject] = json["hits"] as [AnyObject]
        for itemDictionary in results {
            let name: String? = itemDictionary["_id"]?["_fields"]?["item_name"]? as? String
            let idValue:String? = itemDictionary["_id"]? as? String
            if (name? != nil && idValue? != nil) {
                searchResult = (name: name!, idValue: idValue!)
                usdaItemsSearchResults += [searchResult]
            }
        }
    }
    return usdaItemsSearchResults
}
```

We are getting there thanks to the excellent support. In this new version I'm getting the error "use of unresolved identifier 'name'". This error occurs at the level of the flow control `if (name? != nil ...)`.

This is the new code:

```
        class func jsonAsUSDAIdAndNameSearchResults (json: NSDictionary) -> [(name: String, idValue: String)] {

    var usdaItemsSearchResults: [(name: String, idValue: String)] = []
    var searchResult: (name: String, idValue: String)

    if json["hits"] != nil {
        let results:[AnyObject] = json["hits"]! as [AnyObject]
        for itemDictionary in results {
            if let name = ((itemDictionary["_id"] as! NSDictionary)["_fields"] as! NSDictionary)["item_name"] as? String {break}
            if let idValue = itemDictionary["_id"] as? String {break}
            if (name? != nil && idValue? != nil) {
                searchResult = (name: name!, idValue: idValue!)
                usdaItemsSearchResults += [searchResult]
            }
        }
    }
    return usdaItemsSearchResults
}
```

Grimxn deserves a medal! We are almost there. Following code no longer shows any problems but we are hitting a breakpoint when running it. It seems to have a problem with the casting.

```
class func jsonAsUSDAIdAndNameSearchResults (json: NSDictionary) -> [(name: String, idValue: String)] {

        var usdaItemsSearchResults: [(name: String, idValue: String)] = []
        var searchResult: (name: String, idValue: String)

        if json["hits"] != nil {
            let results:[AnyObject] = json["hits"]! as [AnyObject]
            for itemDictionary in results {
                let fields: NSDictionary = (itemDictionary["_id"]? as NSDictionary)["_fields"]? as NSDictionary
                let name:String? = fields["item_name"] as? String
                let idValue:String? = itemDictionary["_id"]? as? String
                if (name? != nil && idValue? != nil) {
                    searchResult = (name: name!, idValue: idValue!)
                    usdaItemsSearchResults += [searchResult]
                }
            }
        }
        return usdaItemsSearchResults
    }
```

It is solved. The code works as follows. I made a wrong drill down. Truly thanks, I have learned a lot:

```
         class func jsonAsUSDAIdAndNameSearchResults (json: NSDictionary) -> [(name: String, idValue: String)] {

    var usdaItemsSearchResults: [(name: String, idValue: String)] = []
    var searchResult: (name: String, idValue: String)

    if json["hits"] != nil {
        let results:[AnyObject] = json["hits"]! as [AnyObject]
        for itemDictionary in results {
            let name:String? = (itemDictionary["fields"]? as NSDictionary)["item_name"] as? String
            let idValue:String? = itemDictionary["_id"]? as? String
            if (name? != nil && idValue? != nil) {
                searchResult = (name: name!, idValue: idValue!)
                usdaItemsSearchResults += [searchResult]
            }
        }
    }
    return usdaItemsSearchResults
}
```

Comment: Well, your old code doesn't compile in 1.2 as far as I can see, so I guess your new code will "have the same use".  The particular error in the old code (multiple times) is that `xxx["key"] as [AnyObject]` is wrong - `xxx["key"]` is an optional. Also, you start on the wrong track - try working with constructs like `if let results = json["hits"] {`.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html

Comment: I'm using 6.1.1. In that version the old code works like a charm. Could be that in 1.2 some optionals ought to be unwrapped. But I'm mostly curious about the name statement. Is that correct or wrong?

Comment: I believe even in old versions `json["hits"]` would still return nil if there was no such entry - that's why they changed the language. As regards your `name` you could (in 1.2) use something like `if let idValue = itemDictionary["_id"], name = idValue["_fields"]["item_name"] {` - I do recommend that you update to the current version of the language.

Comment: You're right I ought to update to 1.2. I'm very glad you are suggesting me this if let name = itemDictionary["_fields"]["item_name"] way. It is indeed brief and clearer than all those if loops. But what was wrong with my optional chaining?

Comment: I just replaced the statement by if let name = itemDictionary["_id"]["_fields"]["item_name"] {}. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Sorry - should probably be something like `if let name = ((itemDictionary["_id"] as! NSDictionary)["_fields"] as! NSDictionary)["item_name"] as? String {}`

Comment: I'm getting now an error in my if clause. It throws "use on unresolved identifier name". I deleted the ? after name and idValue in the if clause as the if let should no longer require a question mark after name nor idValue.

Comment: the {} gave an error too by the way. This got solved by removing them as nothing needs to be done but assigning the value.

Comment: Type 'int' does not conform to protocol 'StringLiteralConvertible' disappeared as error though :)

Comment: I no longer get an error using if let name = ((itemDictionary["_id"] as! NSDictionary)["_fields"] as! NSDictionary)["item_name"] as? String. Thanks for that solution. But the code as a whole does not work. Now the if clause gives an error. if (name != nil && idValue != nil) {
                    searchResult = (name: name, idValue: idValue)
                    usdaItemsSearchResults += [searchResult]
                } yields error "use of unresolved identifier 'name'"

Comment: I've lost track of your code changes, now. Edit your question to show what you've tried, as it's no longer clear to me where the error is appearing. If it's in the `if name != nil ...` that's one thing, if it's in `searchResult = (name:name...` that's another, 'cos that's wrong - `name` would still be an optional there, and needs unwrapped...

Comment: I've edited it. Problem occurs at the if (name? != nil... clause. I put a ? after name because it is still an optional. Removing the ? doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Your answer using the if let ought to work. The goal however was to eliminate all the if clauses. Do you have any idea why this line of code will not work properly: let name:String? = ((itemDictionary["_id"] as! NSDictionary)["_fields"] as! NSDictionary)["item_name"] as? String

Answer (score 1):

It is solved. The code works as follows. I made a wrong drill down. Truly thanks, I have learned a lot:

```
         class func jsonAsUSDAIdAndNameSearchResults (json: NSDictionary) -> [(name: String, idValue: String)] {

    var usdaItemsSearchResults: [(name: String, idValue: String)] = []
    var searchResult: (name: String, idValue: String)

    if json["hits"] != nil {
        let results:[AnyObject] = json["hits"]! as [AnyObject]
        for itemDictionary in results {

            let fields: NSDictionary = itemDictionary["fields"]? as NSDictionary
            let name:String? = fields["item_name"] as? String
            let idValue:String? = itemDictionary["_id"]? as? String
            if (name? != nil && idValue? != nil) {
                searchResult = (name: name!, idValue: idValue!)
                usdaItemsSearchResults += [searchResult]
            }
        }
    }
    return usdaItemsSearchResults
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the line `let name: String? = itemDictionary["_id"]?["_fields"]?["item_name"]? as? String`
 
As per your old code you can get the field object from itemDictionary directly.

```
func jsonAsUSDAIdAndNameSearchResults (json: NSDictionary) -> [(name: String, idValue: String)] {

var usdaItemsSearchResults: [(name: String, idValue: String)] = []
var searchResult: (name: String, idValue: String)

if json["hits"] != nil {
    let results: [AnyObject] = json["hits"] as [AnyObject]
    for itemDictionary in results {
        let name: String? = itemDictionary["_fields"]?["item_name"]? as? String
        let idValue:String? = itemDictionary["_id"]? as? String
        if (name? != nil && idValue? != nil) {
            searchResult = (name: name!, idValue: idValue!)
            usdaItemsSearchResults += [searchResult]
        }
    }
}
return usdaItemsSearchResults
```

}
Since you are checking for nil value in a if loop, it should work.

Comment: What would be the correct line for let name = ... if I wouldn't go the if let name = itemDictionary["_fields"]?["item_name"] way?

Comment: "if loop"? They have if loops? Yahoo! At last!

Comment: Grimxn probably meant you ought to use if clause :)